# What's the time complexity of this program?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

Okay!! This is not homework!
My question is "Given a string S, find the longest palindromic substring in S. You may assume that the maximum length of S is 1000, and there exists one unique longest palindromic substring." Regular way is O(n * n) and by using Dynamic Programming I got a better way which is very similar to following program.
As I know, O(n) and O(2n) could be considered as same. So O(n * n/2) is still equivalent to O(n*n)?

here is codes:

```
for(int i =0; i < n; i++)
{
  for(int j = 0; j< i; j++)
  {
    if (array[i][j] != 0)
    array[i][j] = -1;
  }
}
```

Comment: What do _you_ think  it is?

Comment: just enough to be solvable before homework is due.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev  Hey guys, this is not homework. I am just wondering. I worked with a problem using a algorithms with o(n*n), and I was trying to find out a way using o(n). Here I got a way using DP like this between o(n) and o(n*n). So I am just curious.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

While this honestly looks like a homework question, I'm going to answer it anyways and hope I can help explain it along the way:

First, you have a nested loop.  In general, nested loops are often of time complexity O(n<sup>2</sup>) if the maximums of each loop are related to n.

In your case, I'll break it down into a visual representation and hope it makes sense:

Imagine a square with width and height n (the maximum value of your first/outer loop).  For this case I will pick n = 5:

```
o  o  o  o  o  
o  o  o  o  o  
o  o  o  o  o  
o  o  o  o  o  
o  o  o  o  o
```

Now, with this square, you can image each row to be one iteration of i, while each column will represent your j index and how far you reach. When we label which o's in the table that will be visited in our algorithm, we will see a neat pattern.

If you step through it yourself, by the time you are done you will see this result:

```
o  o  o  o  o  
x  o  o  o  o  
x  x  o  o  o  
x  x  x  o  o  
x  x  x  x  o
```

From here we can see that **roughly half the square has been visited**.  Since we know the square has an area of n<sup>2</sup> we can then say we visited n<sup>2</sup>/2 parts of the square.  Therefore, the running time is also O(n<sup>2</sup>/2) which then reduces to O(n<sup>2</sup>) because coefficients can be ignored.

Comment: You are helping *no one*, not even the OP, by posting this.  By posting this, you've effectively done the OP's homework for them, and only encourage people to ask more of the same, because *someone* will always answer questions no matter how low-effort or off-topic.

Comment: It's not my problem the OP wants to cheat. I'm not their mother.  What I did do was try to explain why it was the answer it was so that it might help them understand instead of just giving them the answer. This answer may also be helpful to others who find this question later.

Comment: Really Great answer!.. but there are other ways to post great explanations on web, like writing a blog, and leave it up to students to google them. Spoon feeding helps no one.  Have to agree with @LittleBobbyTables

Comment: By "the blog" do you mean something specific? Otherwise I don't have one to post to, and I usually come to stack overflow for problems first and avoid blogs, as I have seen others do.   Honestly I know people may not agree with he fact that I answered, but that's not the point of down voting. As you said my answer was a good one and therefore helpful. Down voting the question I can understand, but not the answer.

Comment: @bajuwa  Thank you! This is not homework. I am just wondering. I worked with a problem using a algorithms with o(nn), and I was trying to find out a way using o(n). Here I got a way using DP like this between o(n) and o(nn). So I am just curious. Technically it is still  O(nn)? which means O(nn) == O(nn/2)?

Comment: @Shaunak Thank you for your consideration. You just thought too much.

Comment: Glad to know this isn't homework =) perhaps you could explain what you just said as an edit in your question? That might dispel some of the hate ;)   as for your further questions I need more details to come up with a concrete comparison, but in general you ignore coefficients since O(nn/2) is still going to take much longer than O(n) for large n

Comment: @bajuwa There's no hate here.. but principles.. FWIW I did not down-vote your answer. I actually like it.

YutaoXing regardless of weather or not it's a homework question, the question indicates no efforts on your part. Please try to explain what you tried, and what you need help in understanding.

Comment: @bajuwa     I edited description of this problem. Thank you guys!!

Comment: @Shaunak I edited description of this problem. Thank you guys!!

Comment: @YuTao Xing : if this answer was what you needed then please accept it.  As for your edit regarding running times, my answer still applies (particularly the part about dropping coefficients)